# Identify Object with dynamically changing properties in QTP

Tags: qtp

I am trying to identify a web table whose properties are changing dynamically. The properties are as below:
outertext   EMR_inTemp_1(VALUE IN THE 1,1 CELL)
innertext   EMR_inTemp_1(VALUE IN THE 1,1 CELL)
name        TABLE(4 other web tables have the same name)

Can any body please help how web table can be identified?

Comment: Do you want to save the value somewhere or just identify a cell based on the value?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, nor what you´ve tried so far. Please refine your question.